# display value inside pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created this pie chart with some help from another question, and everything works fine, except that no matter what I try, then I can't seem to figure out how to put the value inside each part of the Pie chart.

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var numbers = [200, 60, 15]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; // Colors of each slice

for (var e = 0; e < numbers.length; e++) {
  myTotal += numbers[e];
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, can.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" />
```

Do anyone know how I can put the values from `numbers` inside the pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var numbers = [15, 90 ,15, 90, 60, 15, 120]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ['black', 'magenta', 'red', 'purple', 'green', 'blue', 'pink']; // Colors of each slice
var x, y;

for (var e = 0; e < numbers.length; e++) {
  myTotal += numbers[e];
}

var fillText = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, can.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.font = "12px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";

  // Calc by @Liora Haydont
  x = (can.width / 4) * Math.cos(lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * ((numbers[i]/2) / myTotal)));
  y = (can.height / 4) *  Math.sin(lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * ((numbers[i]/2) / myTotal)));
  
  // set a slight offset for numbers so they are centered
  let tmp = [(numbers[i]), (x-8+(can.width/2)), (y+5+(can.width/2))]
  fillText.push(tmp);
  
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal);
}

// draw text afterwards so it doesnt get overpainted
for( let i = 0; i < fillText.length; i++ ) {
  ctx.fillText(fillText[i][0], fillText[i][1], fillText[i][2]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 3):

This is where you realise that trigonometry is actually usefull.
To get the xy of a angle of a circle, there is a simple formula:

```
x = radius *  cos(angle)
y = radius *  sin(angle)
```

Now all you need to do is find the angle of the center of each number.
Since you already work with you lastend, I simply have to divise your current angle by 2

```
lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * ((numbers[i]/2) / myTotal));
```

With this, you'll get the x and y from the center. You then simply have to add the x,y of the center to get the position of your text.

**Your snippet updated:**

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var numbers = [200, 60, 15]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; // Colors of each slice
var x, y;

for (var e = 0; e < numbers.length; e++) {
  myTotal += numbers[e];
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, can.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.font = "12px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  //I divided the width by 4 so that it is halfway to the middle
  x = (can.width / 4) * Math.cos(lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * ((numbers[i]/2) / myTotal)));
  y = (can.height / 4) *  Math.sin(lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * ((numbers[i]/2) / myTotal)));
  ctx.fillText(numbers[i], x+(can.width/2)  , y+(can.width/2));
 
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where do you want to put the numbers, but check this example, you must use **HTML Canvas Text**, and some properties like **font, fillStyle and fillText**

```js
var can = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var numbers = [200, 60, 15]; // If you add more data values make sure you add more colors
var myTotal = 0; // Automatically calculated so don't touch
var myColor = ['red', 'green', 'blue']; // Colors of each slice

for (var e = 0; e < numbers.length; e++) {
  myTotal += numbers[e];
}

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.arc(can.width / 2, can.height / 2, can.height / 2, lastend, lastend + (Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal)), false);
  ctx.lineTo(can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();
  lastend += Math.PI * 2 * (numbers[i] / myTotal);
      }
  
  ctx.font = "12px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText(numbers[0] , 50 , 50); // Adjust the x and y here
  ctx.fillText(numbers[1] , 100 , 50);
  ctx.fillText(numbers[2] , 180 , 90);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" />
```

See this tutorial on [HTML Canvas Text](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp)

Comment: I like the answer, but is there a way to make the text placement more dynamic, Since `[200, 60, 15]` is just fictive numbers for the example.

Comment: It depends on what type of dynamic text you want

Comment: As you can see it would make sense that `200` is located somewhat close to the middle of the red part and so on, just like the `15` inside the blue, just dynamic. Because with the numbers coming from a database I can't know how big each part of the pie chart will be-